# Sql Insert the same row multiple times

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write a stored procedure which will take rows from a table like the one below

[image]

and insert them as many times as the value of the Quantity column. It should also assign a unique name & number to the rows inserted.

The end result should look something like the screenshot below

[image]

I can get very close to the what I want by the SQL below
[Source](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic911157-338-1.aspx)

```
INSERT INTO dbo. MyTable (....)
SELECT
    t1.Name + ' (' +   CAST(E.n as VARCHAR(3)) + ')',
    @Prefix + ' - ' + ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY t1.Name )
FROM
    MyFirstTable t1
    JOIN ....
    JOIN .....
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT TOP 500 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM sys.columns)E(n)
WHERE 
    E.n <= t1.Quantity
    AND....
```

The above statement works because I do know that quantity will never exceed 500 but I'm not a big fan of the way it is done. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

I'm not very experienced in sql.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using a [table of numbers](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1). I personally have an actual table in the database with 100K numbers instead of generating it on the fly as you do.

Comment: Thumbs up! I like the article. Very informative. Unfortunately, it'll be tough to get other devs on my project on board with that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have already figured out what you need for the most part. As far as the `top 500` not exceeding goes, you could either leave it there or remove it. I think this is what you may be looking for:

```
SELECT
    id,        --not sure where this id comes from but looks different in your output
    CASE 
      WHEN E.n-1 > 0
        THEN t1.Name + ' (' +   CAST(E.n-1 as VARCHAR(3)) + ')'
     ELSE t1.Name
     END as  Name,
    @prefix + ' - ' + cast(ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY t1.id) as varchar(10)) as Number
FROM
    test t1
    JOIN ...
    JOIN ...
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM sys.columns)E(n)
WHERE 
    E.n <= t1.Quantity
    AND ....;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d874/5/0)

Comment: That Cross Join doesn't bug me as much without the TOP 500. Thanks :)